# Sphinx matlab documentation error: missing module 'std'

Tags: python, matlab, python-3.x, python-sphinx

I'm trying to document my MATLAB classes using sphinx. But whenever I want to run `make html` I get the following error:

```
% make html
sphinx-build -b html -d _build/doctrees   . _build/html
Running Sphinx v1.4.6

Extension error:
Could not import extension sphinxcontrib.matlab (exception: No module named 'std')
make: *** [Makefile:53: html] Error 1
```

I'm on ArchLinux and tried the following installation ways, but all result in the same problem:

Try 1:

```
yaourt -S python-sphinx # (was already installed by default, just to show that the package came from arch repo)
sudo pip install -U sphinxcontrib-matlabdomain
```

Try 2:

```
yaourt -R python-sphinx # (I also removed all dependencies)
sudo pip -U install sphinx
sudo pip -U install -U sphinxcontrib-matlabdomain
```

In neither of the cases it worked (always the error from above). In each try I also verified that the `std` module is there via

```
# ll /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sphinxcontrib*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 326 Sep 28 11:02 /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sphinxcontrib_blockdiag-1.5.5-py2.7-nspkg.pth
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 326 Sep 28 11:00 /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sphinxcontrib_matlabdomain-0.2.7-py3.5-nspkg.pth

/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sphinxcontrib:
total 152
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11457 Sep 28 11:02 blockdiag.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 37815 Jun 20  2015 mat_documenters.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 27529 Oct  7  2014 matlab.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 46088 Jun 20  2015 mat_types.py
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   126 Sep 28 11:03 __pycache__
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 22278 Feb  7  2014 std.py

/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sphinxcontrib_blockdiag-1.5.5.dist-info:
total 32
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1033 Sep 28 11:02 DESCRIPTION.rst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    4 Sep 28 11:03 INSTALLER
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2127 Sep 28 11:02 METADATA
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1193 Sep 28 11:02 metadata.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   14 Sep 28 11:02 namespace_packages.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1054 Sep 28 11:03 RECORD
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   14 Sep 28 11:02 top_level.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  110 Sep 28 11:02 WHEEL

/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sphinxcontrib_matlabdomain-0.2.7-py3.5.egg-info:
total 40
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1 Sep 28 11:00 dependency_links.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  487 Sep 28 11:00 installed-files.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   14 Sep 28 11:00 namespace_packages.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1 Jun 20  2015 not-zip-safe
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8547 Sep 28 11:00 PKG-INFO
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   28 Sep 28 11:00 requires.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  549 Sep 28 11:00 SOURCES.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   14 Sep 28 11:00 top_level.txt
```

P.S.: my default python has version 3.5.2

Edit 1:

```
% head $(which sphinx-build)
#!/usr/bin/python

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from sphinx import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
% which sphinx-build
/usr/bin/sphinx-build
% sphinx-build --version
Sphinx (sphinx-build) 1.4.6
% python --version
Python 3.5.2
% /usr/bin/python --version
Python 3.5.2
```

Comment: Does your `sphinx-build` run with Python 3.5? What does `head $(which sphinx-build)` give you? Also, what does `which sphinx-build` give?

Comment: @MartinUeding thanks for your comment. I updated the post with some information. I guess that it runs with Python 3.5. Is there a way to find that out for sure?

Comment: You could add a `print()` statement with the Python version to the `conf.py`. But my hunch is that your plugin is designed for Python 2 (like the `feed` plugin in the same repository) and that the new import rules of Python 3 let the import fail. So try to install Sphinx with `python2`, perhaps you have `pip2` on Arch Linux. Then your extension might work.

Comment: @MartinUeding thanks again for your comment. I have `pip` and `pip3`. But both of then give the same paths. Here some excerpt: `% sudo pip3 install -U sphinxcontrib-matlabdomain
Requirement already up-to-date: sphinxcontrib-matlabdomain in /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages` and `% sudo pip install -U sphinxcontrib-matlabdomain
Requirement already up-to-date: sphinxcontrib-matlabdomain in /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages`

Comment: I know on Arch Linux that `python` is `python3` whereas on Fedora and Ubuntu `python` is `python2`. Don't you have an explicit `/usr/bin/pip2`? If not, can you install it?

Comment: @MartinUeding thanks, indeed there is an extra package for pip2 which solves that problem( have no pip, pip2 and pip3 :D) ). I would be happy to accept this as an answer if you write one.

Comment: I removed the `std.py` package, builds for me with python-2.7.12 and sphinx-1.5.1 on Windows - see [matlabdomain-0.2.8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sphinxcontrib-matlabdomain/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extensions in the sphinx-contrib repository seem to be meant for Python 2. The import rules have changed in Python 3, therefore such errors can occur when Python 3 code is run with a Python 2 interpreter.

The solution is to install Sphinx and all its dependencies for Python 2. Your distribution might have `python2-sphinx`. On Fedora and Ubuntu the packages `python-*` are always Python 2 or both, `python3-*` is the Python 3 package.

On Arch Linux I know that `python` is symlinked to `python3`. So there might be additional `python2-*` packages. Install `pip2` (because `pip` is likely to be `pip3` on Arch Linux) and use that to install Sphinx.

You can find out which interpreter is called by running `head -n 1 $(which sphinx-build)` and then check the path.

- `/usr/bin/python`: That is Python 2 on Ubuntu or Fedora, Python 3 on Arch Linux
- `/usr/bin/python3`: Definitely Python 3
- `/usr/bin/python2`: Definitely Python 2
- `/usr/bin/env python`: Similar to the others.

Otherwise one could do a `print` of the Python version inside of the `conf.py` such that it is printed explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version (>=0.2.11) of [sphinxcontrib-matlabdomain](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sphinxcontrib-matlabdomain) supports both Python 2 and 3. I think this should resolve the issue you saw.